# How can i map "object" type property in fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

i write my class and its mapping but when i want to run my project this error has thrown:

```
property mapping has wrong number of columns: Azarakhsh.Domain.HumanResource.Personnel.Core.AdditionalValue.Value type: Object
```

my class and mapping code are here:

```
public partial class AdditionalValue : PersistentObject
{
    virtual public Object Value { get; set; }
}


public class AdditionalValueMap : ClassMap<AdditionalValue>
{
    public AdditionalValueMap()
    {
        Map(p => p.Value)
            .CustomSqlType("sql_variant");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you expecting to persist a System.Object there?

If it's by serializing it, you should use `Serializable` as the NH type and `varbinary(max)` for SQL.

Comment: i have a property that is "object" and user defines its type. so my prop maybe is an integer or string or float or ... . even it might be a generic list of int or anything else. so what can i do?

Comment: So what I wrote is the easiest way to go, but it **won't** use sql_variant; it will be binary-serialized. An alternative is writing a custom `IUserType`. Here's an example that supports primitive types (not lists): https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=987576